# Go back after call Intent.ACTION_VIEW in android

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

My app has 3 activity A, B, C. Activity A calls B. In B, I call Intent.ACTION_VIEW to do authentication with Twitter as below:

```
public static void DoAuthen(Context context, String CallBackUrl) throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthNotAuthorizedException,
        OAuthExpectationFailedException, OAuthCommunicationException {
    httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(context.getString(R.string.Twitter_ConsumerKey), context
            .getString(R.string.Twitter_ConsumerSecret));
    httpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
    String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(httpOauthConsumer, CallBackUrl);
    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
}
```

After authentication, My App is called back at activity B. Here B calls C.
Now if I press Back button, it will navigate to browser (which used to authenticate with Twitter before) rather than to B and then to A. 
How can I resolve this?

Comment: if B calls C it should come back to B after pressing back on C.. strange to know.. i will also try to reproduce this

Comment: Yes, Right. But in case B call Intent.ACTION_VIEW (to request to twitter page) before call C, it does not go back to B directly from C

Comment: What you write in your comments is that your auth activity come backs to b and then b call c.. that means auth activity must have finished..

Comment: @Griggry Comment is right kindly follow that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please refer to [Tasks and Back stack in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html). You can use two tasks in your application - in first one you do your business, in second - authorization. You start authorization with intent flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and use parameter [android:clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Grigory, Could you please give me some sample codes? I can set flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK when I call Intent.ACTION_VIEW but I dont know how to use parameter android:clearTaskOnLaunch with this.

Comment: @nguyen-minh-binh try to read this: http://intridea.com/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode?blog=company

Answer (score 1):

I added the following flags to the ACTION_VIEW intent and it solved the going back to browser problem

```
consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                    "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                    "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
Intent oauthIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));        
oauthIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
oauthIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
oauthIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you can override back button to go directly to B

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        startActivity(C.this,B.class);
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this way before. It works. But when I press Home button to minimize my app then press and hold button Home to open my app again, I will show activity B instead of A.