# Map Activity won't stop on backpress

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have a list of places. When the user clicks on every item, another `Activity` shows items placed on map activity. I'm sending LatLng with `putExtra` on item click.

Everything works fine, but my problem is when the user backpresses from map activity, the map shows again, some kind of refreshing (to exit the map activity the user has to press twice!).

On back press `kill` , `finish()` or other killing page won't work!

**First activity**

```
lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BimarestanMAP.class);
    switch(position) {
      case 0 :
        intent.putExtra("name", str1);
        intent.putExtra("lat", bim1a);
        intent.putExtra("lan", bim1l);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
```

**Map activity:**

```
initilizeMap();
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
str1 = bundle.getString("name");
final double lat = bundle.getDouble("lat");
final double lan = bundle.getDouble("lan");

Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  .position(new LatLng(lat, lan))
  .title(str1)
  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
marker.showInfoWindow();
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lan), 15));

@Override
protected void onResume () {
  super.onResume();
  initilizeMap();
}

private void initilizeMap() {
  if (googleMap == null) {
    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    // check if map is created successfully or not
    if (googleMap == null) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sorry no map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exit from google maps intent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838812/exit-from-google-maps-intent-in-android)

Comment: why you are calling initilizeMap() twice ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, And thanks;
Added:
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

in item intent;

Comment: Don't post your own answer when other has given right answer . accept that as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add following intent Flags

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```